# how to get the Nth element below div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the Nth element class using jQuery in the following example? I want to remove class `selected` of element `zone` two levels down. That's why I used `next().next()` but it's not getting class selected of `li`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on("click", "#myId", function() {
                // $("#zone > .CaptionCont  > .optWrapper ul li").removeClass('selected');
                var op = $("#zone").next().next();
                console.log(op[0]);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="zone"></div>
        <p class="CaptionCont SelectBox search" title=" Volvo ">
            <span class=""> Volvo </span>
            <label><i></i></label>
            <input type="text" class="search-txt" value="" placeholder="Enter here.">
        </p>
        <div class="optWrapper multiple">
            <ul class="options">
                <li class="opt selected"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>Volvo</label>
                </li>
                <li class="opt"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>Saab</label>
                </li>
                <li class="opt"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>Mercedes</label>
                </li>
                <li class="opt"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>Audi</label>
                </li>
                <li class="opt"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>BMW</label>
                </li>
                <li class="opt"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>Porche</label>
                </li>
                <li class="opt"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>Ferrari</label>
                </li>
                <li class="opt"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>Mitsubishi</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="OK" id="myId" value="Ok" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `$('#zone').next('.optWrapper').find('.selected')`

Comment: Or `$('#zone + .optWrapper .selected');`

Comment: is it possible to remove the selected class by this way ,i want to remove class='selected'

Comment: Yes. Add `.removeClass(".selected")`

Comment: Try `$('#zone').nextAll('.optWrapper').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');`

Comment: Thanks @ phobia82 it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the selected class using

```
$('#zone').siblings('.optWrapper').find('.selected').removeCl‌​ass('selected');
```

or

`$('#zone').nextAll('.optWrapper').find('.selected').removeCl‌​ass('selected');`

(Better performing as it will only look for next elements of the selected element )

```js
$(function(){

  $('#zone').siblings('.optWrapper').find('.selected').removeClass("selected");
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on("click", "#myId", function() {
                // $("#zone > .CaptionCont  > .optWrapper ul li").removeClass('selected');
                var op = $("#zone").next().next();
                console.log(op[0]);
            });
        </script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="zone"></div>
        <p class="CaptionCont SelectBox search" title=" Volvo ">
            <span class=""> Volvo </span>
            <label><i></i></label>
            <input type="text" class="search-txt" value="" placeholder="Enter here.">
        </p>
        <div class="optWrapper multiple">
            <ul class="options">
                <li class="opt selected"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>Volvo</label>
                </li>
                <li class="opt"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>Saab</label>
                </li>
                <li class="opt"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>Mercedes</label>
                </li>
                <li class="opt"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>Audi</label>
                </li>
                <li class="opt"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>BMW</label>
                </li>
                <li class="opt"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>Porche</label>
                </li>
                <li class="opt"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>Ferrari</label>
                </li>
                <li class="opt"><span><i></i></span>
                    <label>Mitsubishi</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="OK" id="myId" value="Ok" />
    </body>
</html>
```